# PHP values that come before negative and after numbers

Tags: php, arrays

That probably doesn't make a ton of sense.   I want to know if there are any values that you could put in an array and sort it and it would come before all negative entries or after all positive entries.

```
    $keys = array('m1' => 1, -500 => 1, 0 => 1, 1000 => 1, 'm' => 1, 5000 => 1, );

    foreach($keys as $k => $v){
    echo $k . '<br />';
}
```

Returns

```
  -500
  m
  0
  m1
  1000
  5000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?

$keys = array('m1' => 1, -500 => 1, 0 => 1, 1000 => 1, 'm2' => 1, 5000 => 1, );

ksort($keys, SORT_STRING);

foreach($keys as $k => $v){
    echo $k . '<br />';
}

?>
```

Will return:

```
-500
0
1000
5000
m1
m2
```

Make sure to keep all the string keys lowercase if you want them in the right order too. This will put the strings after all integers.

Heres an example of the method: http://codepad.org/IBc3wnso

The only way I can think of to *simply* get your non `int` keys first, is to prefix them with `--`:

```
<?

$keys = array('--m2' => 1, -500 => 1, 0 => 1, 1000 => 1, '--m1' => 1, 5000 => 1, );

ksort($keys, SORT_STRING);

foreach($keys as $k => $v){
    echo $k . "\n";
}

?>
```

Will return:

```
--m1
--m2
-500
0
1000
5000
```

Example: http://codepad.org/rwbrj3rJ

It's a bit of a hack though. There's probably a better way to accomplish that.

Comment: I never tried it because I it says that's the default method it uses to sort. Any chance you know of something that in such a sort would be sorted behind the negative values. IE m, -500, 0 .... I am looking for what M would need to be to be in that order.  I have tried something like -m, however that falls between -500 and 0.

Comment: You could always reverse it and use krsort, however all your keys would be backwards, ie `m2, m1, 500, 0, -500`

Comment: Unfortunately in this situation I need to be able to fall before the -500.  The lists I am showing are 1/1000 of what the actual lists are.  I may be able to come up with something, but I am trying to minimize processing.

Comment: Also, `SORT_REGULAR` is the default flag (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Comment: It's my err, I was looking at that earlier before posting trying to come up with a solution on my own.

Answer (score 0):

If you want single chars as array keys, try chr(0) and chr(255).

Wait a minute: if you keep changing the question it's difficult to reply.

You have -500 as a key: this is not a single char.

Then, use -PHP_INT_MAX for lower value and PHP_INT_MAX for upper value.

Comment: I am talking about a single character.  That you could use an an array key.

Comment: I assumed values=integers.